# Geometric properties of Snub Icosidodecadodecahedron and Medial Hexagonal Hexecontahedron ($U46$ and $U46'$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, intuition, solid-geometry

I would like to calculate the closed form of some values ​​relating to $U46$ and $U46'$ (especially angles and volumes).

I found [this site](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/SnubIcosidodecadodecahedron.html) where the values are given in term of root of equations

> Premise: all solutions must depend on
> $\xi:=\sqrt{\rho+\phi\rho^{2}}$ and $\rho$
> where $\phi$ is the golden constant and $\rho$ is the plastic constant.

## 1. Dihedral angle of U46

As regards the calculation of the dihedral angles of $U46$, it is required to find the two real solutions of:

$$91125 x^6−425250x^5+888975x^4−607500x^3+53955x^2−690x+3481$$

I factored this polynomial into
$$p_1(x)=135\sqrt{5}x^{3}-45(7\sqrt{5}\color{red}{+}10)x^{2}+3(147\sqrt{5}\color{red}{+}340)x-101\sqrt{5}\color{red}{-}218$$
and
$$p_2(x)=135\sqrt{5}x^{3}-45(7\sqrt{5}\color{red}{-}10)x^{2}+3(147\sqrt{5}\color{red}{-}340)x-101\sqrt{5}\color{red}{+}218$$

The real solutions of $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$ can be expressed in terms of $\rho$ and $\xi$

The **real** solutions are $x_1\approx 0.2565$ and $x_2\approx 0.9836$

## Update

I solved this part: $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the solutions of

$$x^2-\frac{2(\rho+3)}{3(\rho+1)}x+\frac{51-13\rho}{45(3\rho+1)}=0$$

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{\rho+3}{\rho+1}\mp\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\frac{7\rho-4}{\rho+3}\right)$$

> Technically instead of the $\sqrt{5}$ there should be a $\xi$, but as a result I think it is acceptable

## 2. Volume of U46

To calculate the volume of $U46$, however, I solved the equations given for the vertices:

**"SRP"="square-root of a root of the polynomial"**

> C0  = 0.105398765906697216676314189282
> C1  = 0.139623637868037118589881535187
> C2  = 0.184961940339626297836961737414
> C3  = 0.245022403774734335266195724469
> C4  = 0.410877732043017261285800591418
> C5  = 0.438898343962682737883306417824
> C6  = 0.525190497798036582742263736641
> C7  = 0.544297109869379954559620607106
> C8  = 0.581416517652346986253630835588
> C9  = 0.695729283407366307710093980810
> C10 = 0.770212901572770918008459461110
> C11 = 0.835352921275403426299975515997
> C12 = 0.955174841912397215845421198524
> C13 = 1.02031486161502972413693725341
> C14 = 1.10660701545038356899589457223

> C0  = SRP:  4096 x^6 - 5120 x^5 + 1536 x^4 - 512 x^3 + 544 x^2  - 96*x + 1
>
> C1  = SRP:  4096 x^6 - 5120 x^5+ 3840 x^4 - 1792 x^3 + 480 x^2 - 60*x + 1
> C2  = SRP:  4096x^6 - 1024x^5- 1024x^4 + 64x^3 + 80x^2 - 32x + 1
> C3  = SRP:  4096x^6 - 2048x^5- 1536x^4 - 704x^3 - 96x^2 - 8x + 1
> C4  = sqrt(6 * (12 - cbrt(12*(9 + sqrt(69))) - cbrt(12*(9 - sqrt(69))))) / 12
> C5  = SRP:  4096x^6 - 5120x^5 + 1536x^4 - 512x^3 + 544x^2 - 96x + 1
> C6  = SRP:  4096x^6 - 7168x^5+ 5120x^4 - 1664x^3 + 96x^2 + 24x + 1
> C7  = sqrt(6*(2+cbrt(4*(101 + 15*sqrt(69)))-cbrt(4*(15*sqrt(69) - 101)))) / 12
> C8  = SRP:  4096x^6 - 5120x^5+ 3840x^4 - 1792x^3 + 480x^2 - 60x + 1
> C9  = SRP:  4096x^6 - 10240x^5+ 8960x^4 - 3648x^3 + 640x^2 - 20x + 1
> C10 = SRP:  4096x^6 - 1024x^5 - 1024x^4 + 64x^3 + 80x^2 - 32x + 1
> C11 = SRP:  4096x^6 - 7168x^5+ 5120x^4 - 1664x^3 + 96x^2 + 24x + 1
> C12 = sqrt(3 * (3 + cbrt(12 * (9 + sqrt(69))) + cbrt(12 * (9 - sqrt(69))))) / 6
> C13 = SRP:  4096x^6 - 2048x^5 - 1536x^4 - 704x^3 - 96x^2 - 8x + 1
> C14 = SRP:  4096x^6 - 10240x^5+ 8960x^4 - 3648x^3 + 640x^2 - 20x + 1\

The solutions are:
$$c_{0}=\frac{1}{2\rho^{3}\xi}\qquad c_{1}=\frac{1}{2\rho^{2}\xi}\qquad c_{2}=\frac{1}{2\rho\xi}\qquad c_{3}=\frac{1}{2\xi}\qquad c_{4}=\frac{\sqrt{2-\rho}}{2}$$
$$c_{5}=\frac{\xi}{2\rho^{3}}\qquad c_{6}=\frac{\phi\rho}{2\xi}\qquad c_{7}=\frac{\rho\sqrt{2-\rho}}{2}\qquad c_{8}=\frac{\xi}{2\rho^{2}}\qquad c_{9}=\frac{\phi\rho^{2}}{2\xi}$$
$$c_{10}=\frac{\xi}{2\rho}\qquad c_{11}=\frac{\rho\xi}{2\phi}\qquad c_{12}=\frac{\sqrt{2\rho+1}}{2}\qquad c_{13}=\frac{\xi}{2}\qquad c_{14}=\frac{\rho^{2}\xi}{2\phi}$$

Now the long part will be using these coordinates to get the volume, but it's just long and tedious work, it's not complicated

---

### 3. I'm having difficulty regarding the calculation of volume of $U46'$

> C0  = 0.03581639493949013983380209116851
> C1  = 0.0474466215401124369879652440389
> C2  = 0.105398765906697216676314189282
> C3  = 0.112586641242744945279481298926
> C4  = 0.134722390669839585134028153001
> C5  = 0.37604495239790042473910409039502
> C6  = 0.438898343962682737883306417824
> C7  = 0.486344965502795174871271661863
> C8  = 0.537942209374520181919397458719
> C9  = 0.544297109869379954559620607106
> C10 = 0.608453514277639159564031071848
> C11 = 0.621067356172634760005299814864
> C12 = 0.656883751112124899839101906033
> C13 = 0.725451430403416911803282769524
> C14 = 0.822739079380407825858706772981
> C15 = 0.844874828807502465713253627056
> C16 = 0.870408778751185966979274045269
> C17 = 0.89232145034761490270121887109501
> C18 = 0.928137845287105042535020962264
> C19 = 0.957461470050247410992734925983
> C20 = 0.984498466675539584303135162243
> C21 = 1.173805071579957404913880606454

> C0  = SRP:  102400x^6 - 66560x^5+ 19456x^4 + 8896x^3 - 2768x^2 - 776x + 1
> C1  = SRP:  102400x^6 - 10240x^5 - 18944x^4 - 13184x^3 - 64x^2 - 444x + 1
> C2  = SRP:  4096x^6 - 5120x^5+ 1536x^4 - 512x^3 + 544x^2 - 96x + 1
> C3  = sqrt(30 * (cbrt(4 * (7157 + 885 * sqrt(69)))- cbrt(4 * (885 * sqrt(69) - 7157)) - 28)) / 60
> C4  = SRP:  102400x^6 - 143360x^5 + 97536x^4 - 40128x^3 + 1408x^2 - 68x + 1
> C5  = SRP:  102400x^6 - 168960x^5+ 84736x^4 - 18432x^3 + 1808x^2 - 72x + 1
> C6  = SRP:  4096x^6 - 5120x^5+ 1536x^4 - 512x^3 + 544x^2 - 96x + 1
> C7  = SRP:  102400x^6 - 240640x^5+ 226816x^4 - 114176x^3 + 33152x^2 - 5304x + 361
> C8  = SRP:  1478656x^6- 2528256x^5 + 694016x^4 - 24064x^3 - 240x^2 - 8x + 1
> C9  = sqrt(6 * (2 + cbrt(4 * (101 + 15 * sqrt(69)))- cbrt(4 * (15 * sqrt(69) - 101)))) / 12
> C10 = sqrt(30 * (22 + cbrt(4 * (367 + 15 * sqrt(69)))+ cbrt(4 * (367 - 15 * sqrt(69))))) / 60
> C11 = SRP:  102400x^6 - 66560x^5+ 19456x^4 + 8896x^3 - 2768x^2 - 776x + 1
> C12 = sqrt(15 * (31 - cbrt(4 * (101 + 15 * sqrt(69))) + cbrt(4 * (15 * sqrt(69) - 101)))) / 30
> C13 = SRP:  1478656x^6- 2192384x^5 + 980736x^4 - 134656x^3 + 5200x^2 + 88x + 1
> C14 = SRP:  102400x^6 - 10240x^5- 18944x^4 - 13184x^3 - 64x^2 - 444x + 1
> C15 = SRP:  102400x^6 - 143360x^5 + 27136x^4 + 17472x^3 - 352x^2 - 448x + 121
> C16 = SRP:  1478656x^6- 2192384x^5 + 980736x^4 - 134656x^3 + 5200x^2 + 88x + 1
> C17 = SRP:  102400x^6- 143360x^5 + 97536x^4 - 40128x^3 + 1408x^2 - 68x + 1
> C18 = SRP:  102400x^6 - 240640x^5+ 226816x^4 - 114176x^3 + 33152x^2 - 5304x + 361
> C19 = SRP:  102400x^6- 143360x^5 + 27136x^4 + 17472x^3 - 352x^2 - 448x + 121
> C20 = SRP:  102400x^6- 168960x^5 + 84736x^4 - 18432x^3 + 1808x^2 - 72x + 1
> C21 = SRP:  1478656x^6- 2528256x^5 + 694016x^4 - 24064x^3 - 240x^2 - 8x + 1

The only values I found are:

$$c_{2}=\frac{1}{2\rho^{3}\xi}\qquad c_3=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{5\rho-6}{4\rho+7}}\qquad c_{6}=\frac{\xi}{2\rho^{3}}\qquad c_9=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\rho+3}{2\rho+1}}\qquad c_{10}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho}}$$
$$\qquad c_{12}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{4\rho+1}{2\rho+1}}$$

The others have these properties:

$$c_0 c_{11}=\frac{\rho-1}{4(2\rho+1)}\qquad c_1 c_{14}=\frac{2-\rho}{4(\rho+3)}\qquad c_4 c_{17}=\frac{\rho-1}{4(2-\rho)}\qquad c_5 c_{20}=\frac{1}{4(2-\rho)}$$
$$c_7 c_{18}=\frac{10\rho-3}{4(7-\rho)}\qquad c_8 c_{21}=\frac{4\rho+5}{4(16-9\rho)}\qquad c_{13} c_{16}=\frac{4\rho+5}{4(16-9\rho)}\qquad c_{15} c_{19}=\frac{5\rho+3}{4(3\rho-1)}$$
$$\frac{c_{21}}{c_{13}}=\phi\qquad \frac{c_{16}}{c_8}=\phi$$

I need some help finding the some of them.

---

Both solids have symmetry Chiral Icosahedral, if it could be useful information.

## 4. Generalization

I should calculate these values ​​for some other pair of solids (which also have more complicated equations).
For each of these pairs I know the characteristic constant that allows the solutions of the equations to be represented in a compact way. I would need a method to quickly find solutions in terms of the characteristic constant.

Comment: I.e. given golden equation $-1 - \phi + \phi^2=0$, plastic equation $-1 - \rho + \rho^3=0$, <???> equation $\rho+\phi\rho^{2} - \xi^2=0$ and set of equations $C(x)=0$. Need find real depends $x(\phi,\rho,\xi)$ for each $C(x)$.

Comment: @DmitryEzhov exactly, I also added relationships between the various constants, so you don't need to calculate 15 constants but only 7. (If I find other relationships I'll add them)